# Source control not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using source control every change showes up as they should, but when I try to commit, push, pull etc nothing happens. This happens with both old and new projects. I have tried to reinstall the app without any luck. How can I fix this? Is there a way to "reset" source control?

Comment: You will have to provide more details. How *exactly* are you "*try to commit, push, pull etc*"? From the UI? From the terminal? Doesn't it show any error? Is your git configured correctly?

Comment: No. Everything works fine from the terminal, it's the source control in the sidebar. No error message at all. Git works fine. When I press the UI button for 'Commit' I get the normal animation that the button is pressed, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you check the bottom tab Output > Git, and check for messages.

Comment: If I stage every file and then commit, it works. Before I could just press commit and it added the files automatically. In the settings I found "Endable Smart Commit" and this was unchecked. It solved my issue. Thanks for assistants, Gino.

Comment: Thank you @Iglebekk `Endable Smart Commit` works. file->settings->search `Endable Smart Commit` and tick the checkbox